# angular unit test about http inside $scope.$watch()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I test http successfully in other context, when in $watch failed.
In my controller, I have something like

```
$scope.$watch('currentNode', function(newValue) {            
    if (newValue) {                               
       $http.get(schemaDefinitionUrl).success(function(data) {
           $scope.schemaCollection = data;
       });
     }
});
```

in my unit test. I strike $watch by $digest(), and I am sure it works well.

```
    describe("httpGet, $config.uri.schemadefinition",function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
            var currentNode = {};
            currentNode = {"name":"la"};
            $scope.currentNode = currentNode;
            $scope.$digest();
            currentNode = {"name":"ha"};
            $scope.currentNode = currentNode;
            $scope.$digest();
        })

        describe("http",function(){
            beforeEach(function(){
                $httpBackend.when('GET', $config.uri.schemadefinition).respond({"age": 16,"name": "li"});                   
                $httpBackend.flush();                 
            });

            it('http response', function(){
                // expect($scope.res.age).toBe(16);  
                // expect($scope.schemaCollection).toBeTruthy();     
            });
            afterEach(function() {
                $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
                $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
            });
        })

    })
```

the test result like

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /js/mock_data/schemadefinition.json
```